# Div Expand to Full Screen Smoothly on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to make a div expand smoothly to fullscreen when clicked. The final product I am going for is similar to when a user clicks a case study on this website https://infinum.co/

So far my code can make the div fullscreen but it jumps because of the position fixed I add. I am not bothered whether the actual animation is handled by CSS or JavaScript/jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".block").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("fullscreen");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.block.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

All I have so far can be found on this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKGeYj

Comment: The problem you are running into is that you cannot `transition` a `position` property which is why you are getting that jumping look. My recommendation is to use `transform` instead of using `position`.

Comment: @James Walker  Did the answer help you. or do tell if you are having any issues with it.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout http://usefulangle.com/post/38/animating-lightbox-with-css-javascript .It contains the animation that you're looking for.

When you're making the position as fixed, you should give the initial *top* & *left* properties as well. You can get the initial *top* & *left* properties using the *getBoundingClientRect* method.
Along with animating *top* & *left*, you should animate *width* & *height* as well for a smoother look.

```
.in-animation {
    animation: inlightbox 0.8s forwards;
    position: fixed !important;
}

@keyframes inlightbox 
{ 
    50% { 
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        height: 200px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make your `#block` fullscreen first and then apply the `position:absolute;` after a delay greater than the fullscreen animation speed.

Here's a working snippet.

```js
var isFullscreen = false;
$("#block").click(function (){ 
    var prop = {};
    var speed = 910;
    if(!isFullscreen){ // MAXIMIZATION
       prop.width = "100%";
       prop.height = "100vh";
       isFullscreen = true;
      $("#block").animate(prop,speed); 
      setTimeout(function() { 
        $("#block").css("position","absolute");
      }, 920);
    }
    else{         
      prop.width = "50%";
      prop.height = "250px";            
      isFullscreen = false;
      $("#block").animate(prop,speed); 
      setTimeout(function() { 
        $("#block").css("position","relative"); 
      }, 920);
    }
    
});
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#block,#blockTwo{
  width:50%;
  height:250px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
#block{
  z-index:100;
}
#blockTwo{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block"></div>
<div id="blockTwo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different approach. I used added and removed classlists using a Javascript onclick function. To make so that the image only took the full pages size rather than spreading downward if there was text or contents at the top of page above the image, I put those images in a div and used classlists there too to remove or to add these areas if the picture expanded. For this to work, you will need to stretch your image. If this fits your website, try the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .image {
                margin: 0px;
                transition: all 0.5s linear;
                background-image: url('https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.4_3Eev4xNVvGA5aRvaevLAHaJa&pid=Api&P=0&w=300&h=300');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
            .image.small {
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;  
                background-size: cover;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
            }
            .image.fullScreen {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-size: cover;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
            }
            .topContent {
                display: contents;
            }
            .bottomContent {
                display: contents;
            }
            .topContent.remove {
                display: none;
            }
            .bottomContent.remove {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topContent">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="image" onclick="imageChange()"></div>
        <div class="bottomContent">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                document.querySelector('.image').classList.add('small')
            }
            function imageChange() {
                if (document.querySelector('.image').classList.contains('small')) {
                    document.querySelector('.image').classList.remove('small')
                    document.querySelector('.image').classList.add('fullScreen')
                    document.querySelector('.topContent').classList.add('remove')
                    document.querySelector('.bottomContent').classList.add('remove')
                } else {
                    document.querySelector('.topContent').classList.remove('remove')
                    document.querySelector('.bottomContent').classList.remove('remove')
                    document.querySelector('.image').classList.remove('fullScreen')
                    document.querySelector('.image').classList.add('small')
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want the image to stretch all the way to the very edge, that should be very possible. Also, with classlists, you could even turn the background black creating a black border.