# Make a Div expand into view from a specific location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div appear and fill the entire viewport (100% width and height) on click of a box. This is my current attempt at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/EmilyEmms/8uzxs2sy/

If you click on the blue area, then a div fades into view. 
But that's just a simple on click method:

```
$("#touchScreen").click(function() {
  window.location = window.location + "#openModal";
});
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to detect the X and Y location of the click inside the blue area, position the fading in div at this location, and then make it come into view by expanding it from a width and height of 0%, to 100%.

The aim is to give an effect similar to how some app icons expand on click from a phone's menu screen to fill the entire viewport.

If it's not possible to detect the location of the click, then would it be possible to set a specific X + Y coordinate in the blue area, from which the div should always expand into view from? (for example, is it possible to make the fading in div, pop out from the center of the blue area every time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this with a quick google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678045/div-expand-to-full-screen-smoothly-on-click . You might be able to adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the clicked position with `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`, and you can use them to get the effect you want

In the code bellow the modal will start expanding from the clicked position

**See snippet:**

```js
$("#touchScreen").click(function(event) {

  var target = $(this).attr("data-target");
   

  $(target).css({
    "left": event.pageX,
    "top": event.pageY
  });

  $(target).animate({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    opacity: 1
  }, 10, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

});

$("#close").click(function(event) {

  $(".modalDialog").animate({
    width: '0',
    height: '0',
    opacity: 0,
  }, 100, function() {
     $(this).css({
    "left": "",
    "top": ""
  });
  });



});
```

```css
#touchScreen {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
  transition: all 400ms ease-in;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: center;
  right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=touchScreen data-target="#openModal">

</div>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a id="close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <h2>Pop Out Div</h2>

    <p>This Div fades in on click, and covers the entire viewport</p>
    <p>Is it possible to detect the location of the click on the blue space and then make this div pop/expand out to fill the screen from that location?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @chiller thanks for your answer, I'm trying to test it, but it's showing me this error: ``{
  "message": "ReferenceError: event is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 78,
  "colno": 5
}`` Do you why ``event`` isn't being understood? Thanks again!

Comment: @Emily try add it as a parameter of the function `$("#touchScreen").click(function(event)....`

Comment: Ah it's working perfectly now @chiller thank you! Btw, I notice that when I close the modal, I'm unable to reopen it again by clicking on the blue area again, is there some way to reset it so that it will always work?

Comment: @Emily i edited my answer...  i tryed to do the animation ising jquery take a lookl

Answer (score 0):

you can use `clientX` and `clientY` to get the position of the click. then position the openModal in that position

```js
$("#touchScreen").click(function(e) {
    var xPos = e.clientX,
    yPos = e.clientY
  window.location = window.location + "#openModal";
 $('#openModal').css({"top":yPos,"left":xPos})
});
```

```css
#touchScreen {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: center;
  right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=touchScreen href="#openModal">

</div>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <h2>Pop Out Div</h2>

    <p>This Div fades in on click, and covers the entire viewport</p>
    <p>Is it possible to detect the location of the click on the blue space and then make this div pop/expand out to fill the screen from that location?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```